# mysql find position in recordset but grab value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql that grabs the wealth ranking (position) of a single player from the `players` recordset. But I need to do a join to the `users` table to ignore banned players while finding the position.

My existing code (checking for player id 5):

```
SELECT z.rank FROM 
    (SELECT p.id, p.name, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM players p, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
    WHERE p.this != 'that' ORDER BY p.cash + p.bank DESC) as z #
    WHERE id=5;
```

So what I need is something like this: (this doesn't work)

```
SELECT z.rank FROM 
    (SELECT p.id, p.name, 
        (SELECT ban FROM u.users WHERE id=p.account_id) as banned, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM players p, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
    WHERE p.this != 'that' AND banned=0 ORDER BY p.cash + p.bank DESC) as z #
    WHERE id=5;
```

Getting too complex for me!

Comment: wouldn't an actual INNER JOIN be better then?

Comment: you could use a 'NOT IN' select rank from players where name not in (select name from users where banned = 1)